# upload files in angular with data

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular and I have an issue with uploading files from different inputs. All the examples I have seen was about uploading files only from one input.

This is what I need for example :

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <lable>type file A</lable>
    <input type='text'>
    <input type='file'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>type file B</lable>
    <input type='text'>
    <input type='file'>
  </div>
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

In my API I want to get the file type A the file type B and the files A and B.
I do not need the API code but I do need to see how to do it in angular.

Comment: Why not make them separate forms and submit the first one programatically while submitting the second one? BTW if you can handle one submission I don't see why you can't handle two? It's just that your backend receives extra information right?

Comment: I need to enforce the user to upload 2 files . and each file has other business purpose , so I need to know witch file it is.

Comment: You can give the inputs  a name...